# React router v6 dom no funciona sin componente desde render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Tengo un problema con react-router-dom 6.0.2.

Estoy aprendiendo a usarlo y no encuentro la manera de devolver en una cierta y determinada ruta, los elementos que renderizo en la configuración de rutas.

Se que quizás no llegue a utilizar este método, pero necesito saber cómo hacerlo correctamente.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class Router extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                   <Route path="/prueba-uno" element={<SeccionPruebas />} />
                    {/* Sin componente */}
                    <Route path="/home/:id" render={(props) => {
                            let id = props.match.params.id;

                            <React.Fragment>
                                <div id="content">
                                    <h1 className="subheader">Pagina HOME</h1>
                                    <h2>{id}</h2>
                                </div>
                            </React.Fragment>
                   
                        }
                    } />

                 </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
            
        );
    }}

export default Router;
```

Sencillamente, la parte que no funciona es la de la ruta /home, la cual simplemente no devuelve nada. Es decir, cuando la ruta no llama a ningún componente y simplemente tiene que devolver o renderizar elementos definidos dentro de la propiedad render del Route.

Posteriormente tuve que cambiar el uso de "component" por "element" en la ruta /prueba-uno para que funcione.

La idea es pasar parámetros en la ruta y que los devuelva en la vista. Sencillo, pero no logro dar con la forma.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que la forma de obtener parámetros del `URL` también cambió en la versión 6 de `react-router`.

En la versión anterior, se podía usar la propiedad `render` del componente `route`, junto con el uso de `props.match.params.id`; tal cual lo muestra el OP en el ejemplo mínimo. (aunque ahí le falta el `return`)

Esto debería funcionar para la versión 6:

```
<Route path="/home/:id" element={<Home />} />
```

Luego:

```
function Home() {
  let params = useParams();
  return <h2>Home: {params.id}</h2>;
}
```

#### Notas de campo

Las props `children` y `render` del componente `<Route>` estan obsoletas en la **versión 6** de `react-router` , por lo que ya no es posible pasar `history/location/match` a componentes. Ahora de deben usar los hooks `useNavigate / useLocation / useParams`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

[Reading URL params React router v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#reading-url-params)

Comment: Claro! así funciona bien, pero quería ver la manera de poder renderizar la vista desde el mismo <Route> sin pasarle un componente en la propiedad "element"

Comment: Las propiedades como `children` y `render` ya son obsoletas en v6, en esta [liga hay mas detalles](https://remix.run/blog/react-router-v6),  saludos

Comment: Bien, creí que se podían seguir usando de esa manera. Muchas gracias!