# No puedo pasar un parámetro por la ruta en un Link a otro componente en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, crud, enlace

Estoy Haciendo un simple Crud en React y tengo problemas en el componente de Editar de mi crud al recibir un parámetro ya que devuelve un objeto vacío,

en App especifico la ruta

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Link} from "react-router-dom"
import Listar from "./components/Listar"
import Crear  from "./components/Crear"
import Editar  from "./components/Editar"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">

        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
            <div className="nav navbar-nav">
                <Link className="nav-item nav-link active" to={"/"}>Sistema <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link>
                <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to={"/crear"}>Crear empleado</Link>
                <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to={"/editar/:id"}>Editar empleado</Link>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
        <Route  path="/" element={<Listar/>}> </Route>
        <Route  path="/crear" element={<Crear/>}> </Route>
        <Route  path="/editar/:id" element={<Editar/>}  
        render={(matchProps) =>
          <Editar
            {...matchProps}
            {...this.props}
            handleMatch={this.handleMatch}
          />
        }/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

En mi componente de Listar al Presionar el botón Editar me lleva a la pantalla de Editar e incluso puedo ver la ruta con el id seleccionado a editar

```
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react'
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom"

class Listar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            datosCargados: false,
            empleados: []
            
        }
    }
    
    cargarDatos() {
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/")
            .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
            .then((datosRespuesta) => {
                console.log(datosRespuesta);
                this.setState({ datosCargados: true, empleados: datosRespuesta })
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }




    borrarDatos = (id) => {

        console.log(id) 

        fetch("http://localhost:8080/?borrar="+id)
            .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
            .then((datosRespuesta) => {
                console.log(datosRespuesta);
               this.cargarDatos()
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.cargarDatos();
        

    }
 
    render() {
        const { datosCargados, empleados } = this.state
        if (!datosCargados) { return (<div>Cargando...</div>); }
        else {

            return (<div>
            <Link className="btn btn-warning" to={"/crear"}>Agregar nuevo empleado</Link> <table className="table">
                 
                <thead>

                   

                    <tr>

                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Correo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {

                        empleados.map(
                            (empleado) => (

                                <tr key={empleado.id}>
                                    <td scope="row"></td>
                                    <td>{empleado.id}</td>
                                    <td>{empleado.nombre}</td>
                                    <td>{empleado.correo}</td>
                                    <td><div className="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                                        
                                      
                                      <Link className="btn btn-warning" to={`/editar/${empleado.nombre}`}>Editar</Link>
                                          
                                        
                                        
                                       
                                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick= {()=>this.borrarDatos(empleado.id)}>Borrar</button>
 
                                    </div></td>

                                </tr>


                            )
                        )
                    }


                </tbody>
            </table></div>);

        }
    }
}
export default Listar;
```

Este es mi componente Editar

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Editar extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            
        }
        

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //console.log(this.props);
        console.log(this.props.match.params);
        
    }

    render(){
       
        return(<div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
                Header
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
                <h4 className="card-title">Title</h4>
                <p className="card-text">Text</p>
            </div>
            <div className="card-footer text-muted">
                Footer
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}

export default Editar;
```

He visto problemas similares en foros pero no una respuesta especifica a unos funciona y otros no, quiero saber si es un problema antes de enviar este dato o no lo estoy recibiendo correctamente. Cabe destacar que al listar es capaz de traer toda la información con normalidad y en la ruta si puedo ver el id que selecciono

Comment: Parece un error en `<Route  path="/editar/:id"` estas combinando las props `element` con `render`; además `render` ya no es valida en la V6, hay que usar `element`.  Aqui te dejo esta publicación que te puede ser de ayuda [Link cambios de V5 a V6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510489/react-router-pasar-propiedades-de-un-componente-por-medio-del-componente-link/510599#510599)

Comment: Aquí otra publicación donde [se explican los cambios de V5 a V6 en relación al envío de parámetros con Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/499285/101408).